# HTML code analyzer

Tags: html

Is there any HTML code analyzing tool that suggests tips to improve the HTML code?

Comment: [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://validator.w3.org/

The most important tool, to ensure validity.

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/30-html-best-practices-for-beginners/
- http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Articles such as this for tips on writing semantic, clean html and avoid common html-diseases like divitus, classitus, optimizing your code, and other best practices.

- http://htmldog.com/
- http://www.opera.com/company/education/curriculum/

Guides such as these which are more in-depth and cover accessibility, development in general, css, JS/DOM ( since DOM *is* what is used for HTML ).

And the mother of all:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/

Though it's not very newbie friendly and I'd recommend guides like htmldog instead, but this would be the go-to source for looking up directly from the source.

Answer (score 3):

For standards?  This one is good: http://validator.w3.org/

Or do you want perf or readability or ...?

Answer (score 1):

[Sitesifter](http://www.sitesifter.co.uk/) is decent (although it identifies issues and links to documentation, it isn't an automated fixup tool — but most problems can't be automatically fixed anyway)

Comment: Nice, haven't heard of it. Remember me from IRC? :p

Answer (score 0):

The reporting feature of Pretty Diff offers suggestions on improving your HTML plus a bunch of stats.

http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify&html

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the list the following code analysis tools:

- Yahoo YSlow! Firebug plugin: http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/
- Google PageSpeed: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/
- Google Speed Tracer: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speed-tracer-by-google/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl/related